# Setting a C++ pointer from Swift

Tags: c++, swift, data-structures

I am using C++ in a Swift app and am trying to pass data in the form of structs in a linked list. The struct is defined in my header file as:

```
struct coordinateNode {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    struct coordinateNode *next;
};
```

In swift I am trying to set the next pointer but get

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When I try:

```
if let v = lastVert {
    lastVert!.next.pointee = node
    lastVert = node
}
```

and when I try

```
if let v = lastVert {
    lastVert!.next = UnsafeMutablePointer<coordinateNode>(&node)
    lastVert = node
}
```

The pointer does not get set.

How do I set this C++ pointer from swift?

**EDIT:**
Turns out the

```
 lastVert!.next = UnsafeMutablePointer<coordinateNode>(&node)
```

does work I was just checking the outcome incorrectly

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but that's not how optional binding works. You should always access the safely unwrapped non-optional value (`v` in your case) inside the `if let` and not force unwrap the optional.

Comment: Yeah the only reason I force unwrap instead of using v is because it was giving me the error "Cannot assign to property: 'v' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: Btw your code doesn't really make sense in this context. Why would you want to set the `next` property of your node to another node, then change the value of your current node to the some other node you just set to `next`? This will make setting next have no effect. What is it that you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: lastVert is a reference to the last object created, as I create new objects I point the 'next' from the last created node to the new one and make the new on the last created object. in the end i should have a linked list of objects, my logic might be flawed I have not been able to test it yet because I cannot get passed this issue

Comment: All I am trying to do with this code is pass data of a 3d object from swift to c++ in an organized way, I figured a linked list would be the best method being I dont know the amount of vertices and faces I will be passing

Comment: @jmerlo26 please don't edit the answer into the question, instead add a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the

```
lastVert!.next = UnsafeMutablePointer<coordinateNode>(&node)
```

does work I was just checking the outcome incorrectly